# Access Run-Time error 2465. Can't find the field '1' referred to in your expression

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need help with this code.

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Private Sub BTNSEARCHOnetoOne_Click()
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT [00_SheetList-Revit-UNION].PACKAGE, [00_SheetList-Revit-UNION].DRAWING, [00_SheetList-Revit-UNION].DISCIPLINE, Hillsboro_OR_xlsx.FileName_Hillsboro_OR, Hillsboro_OR_xlsx.FilePath_Hillsboro_OR FROM Hillsboro_OR_xlsx, WHERE(([00_SheetList-Revit-UNION].PACKAGE) Like '" & Me.TXTKeywordsPackage & "') AND ((Hillsboro_OR_xlsx.FileName_Hillsboro_OR) Like ('*" & ([00_SheetList-Revit-UNION].DRAWING) & "*')"

    Me.SubONEtoONEInsideJoin.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.SubONEtoONEInsideJoin.Form.Requery
    Me.SubONEtoONENullJoin.Form.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub Detail_Click()

End Sub
```

I narrowed it down to this part of the code.

```vb
"...((Hillsboro_OR_xlsx.FileName_Hillsboro_OR) Like ('*" & ([00_SheetList-Revit-UNION].DRAWING) & "*')"
```

As I can take this part out and it works. Is this just syntax?

Comment: Just a heads up this works in a query but when I move it to VBA for a button it dose not.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Really? could you point me in the direction. I have been over this so many times lol.

Comment: There should be an additional `)` at the very end.

Comment: Wow. That was it. Thank you.

Comment: I may as well add that as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your SQL has a number of syntax issues:

1. Comma before `WHERE` clause;
2. Unclosed parentheses in last `WHERE` condition;
3. Unknown alias (`[00_SheetList-Revit-UNION]`) not referenced in `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses. Possibly you meant to cross join this source with `Hillsboro_OR_xlsx`.

See issues with current code with line breaks for illustration:

```vb
SQL = "SELECT [00_SheetList-Revit-UNION].PACKAGE," _
       & "    [00_SheetList-Revit-UNION].DRAWING," _
       & "    [00_SheetList-Revit-UNION].DISCIPLINE," _
       & "    Hillsboro_OR_xlsx.FileName_Hillsboro_OR, " _
       & "    Hillsboro_OR_xlsx.FilePath_Hillsboro_OR " _
       & " FROM Hillsboro_OR_xlsx, " _
       & " WHERE(([00_SheetList-Revit-UNION].PACKAGE) " _
       & "        Like '" & Me.TXTKeywordsPackage & "') " _
       & "   AND " _
       & "      ((Hillsboro_OR_xlsx.FileName_Hillsboro_OR) " _
       & "        Like ('*" & ([00_SheetList-Revit-UNION].DRAWING) & "*')"
```

These issues can be mitigated with parameterized queries (an industry best practice when writing SQL in application code) which is supported in MS Access using [QueryDef Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx). Below are a few advantages and further below adjustment to your setup.

- Saving a stored query instead of a VBA string query allows it is to be optimized by engine and the Access GUI will not allow query to be saved with syntax issues;
- Abstract data from code, specifically VBA variables from SQL statement;
- Readability and maintainability is enhanced.

---

**SQL** *(with no VBA)*

Save below as a stored Access query, using parameters and table aliases.  Also, `[00_SheetList-Revit-UNION]` is cross joined (comma-separated in `FROM` clause) as assumed above.

```sql
PARAMETERS [PackageParam] Text;
SELECT o.PACKAGE, o.DRAWING, o.DISCIPLINE, 
       h.FileName_Hillsboro_OR, h.FilePath_Hillsboro_OR 
FROM Hillsboro_OR_xlsx h, [00_SheetList-Revit-UNION] o    
WHERE ((o.PACKAGE) Like [PackageParam]) 
  AND ((h.FileName_Hillsboro_OR) Like '*' & o.DRAWING & '*');
```

**VBA**

```vb
Private Sub BTNSEARCHOnetoOne_Click()
    Dim qDef As QueryDef
    Dim rst As Recordset

    ' OPEN SAVED QUERY
    Set qDef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")
    ' BIND PARAMETERS
    qDef![PackageParam] = "*" & Me.TXTKeywordsPackage & "*"

    ' BUILD RECORDSET FROM QUERYDEF AND SET TO SUBFORM
    Set rst = qDef.OpenRecordset()        
    Me.SubONEtoONEInsideJoin.Form.Recordset = rst
    Me.SubONEtoONENullJoin.Form.Requery

    Set qDef = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you had something wrong here

you have written

```
Like '" & Me.TXTKeywordsPackage & "'
```

but it has to be like this

```
Like '*" & Me.TXTKeywordsPackage & "*'
```

you had this part wrong

check this below part

```
Like ('*" & ([00_SheetList-Revit-UNION].DRAWING) & "*')
```

Make sure that you are getting the value from textbox. It looks like you are calling table column.

Comment: Thank you Tarun. This is correct as Like '" & Me.TXTKeywordsPackage & "'. It serves the purpose to allow the use of wildcards if the user needs to use wildcards (*) into the textbox TXTkeywordsPackage. Otherwise is is seen as a = without the wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Carefully count your parenthesis.

There should be an additional `)` at the very end.